# iOS - Memory Management advice when passing ManagedObjectContext To Other Views

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a pretty hefty application so far, and it is heavily tied in with Core Data.  I pass a NSManagedObjectContext (along with NSManagedObjects themselves) to other views.

Everything I've read shows that, for the view you are passing the Managed Object and/or Managed Object Context to should have a ***strong*** property that will be used when received.

My question then boils down to this:  Should you set a managed object context or managed object that is received from another controller to nil when you're finished with it, or viewWillDisappear is called or even when didReceiveMemoryWarning is received?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can answer this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing what a little research will do for a guy: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW2